# how to combine multiple instances of navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

for example in my index.html I have a code to detect an update for service worker and the code is like this:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {    
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then(reg => {
    reg.addEventListener('updatefound', () => {
      // A wild service worker has appeared in reg.installing!
      newWorker = reg.installing;    
      newWorker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
        // Has network.state changed?
        switch (newWorker.state) {
          case 'installed':
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // new update available
              showUpdateBar();
            }
            // No update available
            break;
        }
      });
    });
  });

  let refreshing;
  navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', function () {
    if (refreshing) return;
    window.location.reload();
    refreshing = true;
  });
}
```

then in pushManager.js the code is like:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
  .then(function (registration) {
      messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);

      // Request for permission
      messaging.requestPermission()
      .then(function() {
        console.log('Notification permission granted.');
        // TODO(developer): Retrieve an Instance ID token for use with FCM.
        messaging.getToken()
        .then(function(currentToken) {
          if (currentToken) {
            console.log('Token: ' + currentToken)
            sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
          //  updateSubscriptionOnServer(currentToken);
          } else {
            console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
            setTokenSentToServer(false);
          }
        })
......
```

The pushManagr.js is included in both login/index.html and index.html.
I think that calling `navigator.serviceWorker.register` at multiple places will have adverse effect.
so how I can combine the two instances into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, remove the registration of the serviceworker from pushManager.

If you want the registration instance of the serviceworker,use the api getRegistration()

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration(/*scope*/).then(function(registration) {
  if(registration){
    // Move all your firebase messaging code to here
    messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);
  }
});
```